# How many samples are in a frame?

Tags: technical, smpte, samples

I'm trying to find out the number of samples in one frame of SMPTE, does anybody know?

Comment: Samples of what?! What is sample rate of sound? How many frames per second?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, that depends on whether the audio is locked or unlocked as well as the timecode frame rate & audio sampling rate I reckon. can you be more specific?

Answer (score 9):

Samples per frame = Sample Rate / FPS

Comment: Note that the audio frame-rate may be different from the video framerate. Also note that this only calculates the *average* samples per frame; some codecs have a variable number of samples per frame.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the sample rate and the frame rate:

at 24fps and 48000Hz every frame is long (48000hz/24fps)= 2000 sample

at 25 fps and 48000Hz: (48000hz/25fps)= 1920 sample

hope it helps.

best

Answer (score 2):

Guess it depends on the frame rate and sample rate?
If sample rate is 48k and frame rate is 24fps that works out at 2000 a frame (i think!!) lol It's late and I'm quite tired so forgive me if I'm off ;) 
Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

Sample rate divided by frame rate.  You can also select one frame in PT, set the counter to samples and look in the length box.

Answer (score 2):

each frame audio depends on a video if a video is of 96 / 24 then it would be 96000 / 24 you will get a frame's sample so it would be 4000 samples per frame and if it is 48/24 it would be 2000 samples per frame :D